# VBA header logo

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I’m creating a [Word](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Word) document from an [Excel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Microsoft_Excel) file with VBA.
My logo is on sheet "3" in the range of *A1:D6*.
I’m trying to fill up a header on every page of a Word file with a logo, but I have a problem.

I already have the text in a header which is on the right side of a page (but only on the first page), and now I need to put the logo on the left side.

Here is a chunk of my code:

```
Dim headerRange As Object
Set headerRange = wordDoc.Sections(1).Headers(2).Range
wordDoc.PageSetup.DifferentFirstPageHeaderFooter = True

headerRange.Text = "company" & vbCr & _
                   "Address" & vbCr & _
                   "City" & vbCr & _
                   "Country" & vbCr & _
                   "Tel: +7 (727) 777 77 77" & vbCr & _
                   "Fax: +7 (727) 888 88 88" & vbCr & _
                   "company website"

headerRange.ParagraphFormat.Alignment = 2
headerRange.Font.Size = 9
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("3").Range("A1:D6").Copy
Word.Selection.Paste
Dim logoShape As Object
Set logoShape = wordDoc.Sections(1).Headers(1).Shapes(wordDoc.Sections(1).Headers(1).Shapes.Count)
logoShape.Left = wordApp.InchesToPoints(0.5) ' Adjust the position from the left margin
logoShape.Top = wordApp.InchesToPoints(0.5) ' Adjust the position from the top margin
logoShape.Height = wordApp.InchesToPoints(1.5)
logoShape.Width = wordApp.InchesToPoints(1.5)
```

Comment: A far better solution would be to create a template (dotx) in Word with headers/footers etc. already set up. Then you just create your new documents from that.

Comment: I second Timothy's comment. Just use VBA for the things you can't do in the program interface.